# sqoop trying to connect to yarn even when running on MRv1

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, cloudera, sqoop2

I have a cloudera cluster version 5.3.x and when running sqoop client using following command

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://HOST/myapplication --username myuser --direct -table=mytable -m 1 --hive-import --append --hive-table myapplication.tableimp --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/myapplication/tableimp
```

It loops at the following statement. It appears trying to connect to yarn even though we only have MRv1 on our cluster.

```
INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at node/<ipaddress>:8032
INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: node/<ipaddress>:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: node/<ipaddress>:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

I tried the following, which is [documented](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cdh_ig_sqoop2_configure.html) on cloudera, but still no change.

```
alternatives --set sqoop2-tomcat-conf /etc/sqoop2/tomcat-conf.mr1
```

I probably should mention that I dont see a tomcat-conf.mr1 file at the location /etc/sqoop2 on that VM.

Comment: I changed it to /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/etc/sqoop2/tomcat-conf.mr1 ... still doesnt help.

Answer (score 0):

hadoop-conf was pointing to yarn configuration. Using the below command changing it to mapreduce configuration fixed it.

```
[root@node01 bin]# alternatives --config hadoop-conf

There are 4 programs which provide 'hadoop-conf'.

  Selection    Command

-----------------------------------------------

*+ 1           /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn

   2           /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.hdfs

   3           /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.mapreduce

   4           /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.3-1.cdh5.1.3.p0.12/etc/hadoop/conf.empty


Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 3
```